# create text column with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

How can I create a field that is TEXT instead of NVARCHAR? Right now I've got

```
public string Text { get; set; }
```

But that always becomes a nvarchar column, I need a Text column

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to do this. What is your current approach for configuration of column store types? Are you using ModelBuilder? EF Migrations? Attributes?

Comment: I'm just starting out with c# and .net. I know how to use EF migrations yea. Isn't there any kind of annotation that I can put on the attribute that makes it a TEXT column?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4913615/328123 Edit: or Moho's answer :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute)

```
[Column(TypeName = "text")]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

or via Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityTypeHere>()
    .Property( e => e.Text)
    .HasColumnType( "text" );
```

Comment: Which is better and why?

Comment: @OchiFortune The first is to include annotations in your class definition, whereas the second is to specify those attributes in the migration file.