# LINQ-SQL keep requiring money column to be of type Single, even though it already is

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first

The error I get is this:

```
The 'SalesValue' property on 'ItemSale' could not be set to a 'Decimal' value. 
You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Single'.
```

But I already did:

```
[Table("ItemSales")]
public class ItemSale {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ....
    public Single SalesValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my LINQ, simple enough:

```
            from x in database.ItemSales
            select x
```

I am using Entity-Framework Code First

How do I solve this?

Comment: is this code-first? maybe your database already exists and the datatype is different

Comment: Yes, this is EF-Code First.  The database use the "ItemSale" object defined here, so it couldn't have been different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the precision of the column type ? That was an error i once came along which, as far as i remember, was very similar to yours. 
As far as i remember, the precision had to be 2, but had another value.

Comment: This column "SalesValue" is stored in the database as type money, so it doesn't have any precision to change.

Comment: allright, maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829776/generate-money-type-fields-using-code-first-ef-ctp5