# DbMigration.AlterstoredProcedure (Entity Framework migration): How to represent type smallmoney?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

In Entity Framework 6.1, in a C# code-based migration (using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration), when altering a stored procedure definition using the [DbMigration.AlterStoredProcedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176978%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method, what's the proper syntax for adding or modifying a stored procedure parameter of the `smallmoney` type (on SQL Server 2012)?

For example, if I have a migration method that modifies an existing SQL Server stored procedure which takes three parameters, of type `int`, `varchar`, and `smallmoney` respectively:

```
public partial class MyCustomMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.AlterStoredProcedure("dbo.EditItem", c => new
        {
            ItemID = c.Int(),
            ItemName = c.String(),
            ItemCost = /* What goes here to represent the smallmoney SQL Server type? */
        },
        @" (New sproc body SQL goes here) ");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You can try with `ItemCost = c.Decimal(storeType: "smallmoney")`...
Actually you can use any method here e.g. `c.Int()` or `c.Double()` or anything until you explicitly specify the `storeType: "smallmoney"`

Comment: Related question with how to specify a length for string variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341783/entity-framework-data-annotations-set-stringlength-varchar/7341920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, nemesv, for the hint in your comment! What I was missing is that the types being specified while setting up the stored procedure parameters, i.e. "Int" and "String" in:

```
c => new
    {
        ItemID = c.Int(),
        ItemName = c.String(),
        //...
    }
```

...are actually methods, and each of those methods -- on class [System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.ParameterBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.builders.parameterbuilder%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) -- has a set of optional parameters which affect the SQL generated from the migration script.

In the case of a `smallmoney`-type stored procedure argument, I ended up using:

```
    ItemCost = c.Decimal(precision: 10, scale: 4, storeType: "smallmoney")
```

The values of precision: 10 and scale: 4 are from the MSDN article [money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx), which specifies that `smallmoney` has precision (total # of digits) of 10 and scale (# of digits to the right of the decimal point) of 4 (for SQL Server 2008 and higher).

So my complete migration code was:

```
public override void Up()
{
    this.AlterStoredProcedure("dbo.EditItem", c => new
    {
        ItemID = c.Int(),
        ItemName = c.String(),
        ItemCost = c.Decimal(precision: 10, scale: 4, storeType: "smallmoney")
    },
    @" (New sproc body SQL goes here) ");
}
```

Which produced the SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EditItem]
    @ItemID [int],
    @ItemName [nvarchar](max),
    @ItemCost [smallmoney]
AS
BEGIN
    (New sproc body SQL goes here)
END
```